# C++ ifstream class get() method returns the character?

Tags: c++, get, ifstream

I have this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ifstream in;
    in.open(*(argv+1));
    char c;

    while (true) {
        if (in.eof())
            break;
        c = in.get();
        cout << c;
    }
    in.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I read the file which is passed via the command line as the first argument.
While reading the file, I get the char '?' as the last one. Why?

If I remove this line

```
in.open(*(argv+1));
```

I will get only the char '?'.

Comment: do not use `eof()` to control reading from a file.  Use `while(c = in.get())`.  read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @NathanOliver That's not very good either, just use the stream (e.g. `while (in)`)

Comment: To extend on @NathanOliver's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: A question to the OP, why are you using the `*(argv+1)` syntax? It's valid but a little harder to understand than the normal `argv[1]` syntax.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Why would you do that?  You want the read operation to control the loop so the first time the read fails the loop stops.

Comment: @NathanOliver The problem is that the used overload of the [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) function might not return zero on error or end of file, it returns `Traits::eof()` (which defaults to [`std::char_traits::eof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/eof)). There's nothing to say that the value will be zero.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg good point, but `while(in)` will still read past the end of file, doesn't it? Shouldn't you test the state of the stream after each `get`?

Comment: @vsoftco That's true, so better use the `>>` operator as in your answer. :)

Answer (score 9):

In the `while` loop you end up reading `eof`:

```
c = in.get(); // reads eof
cout << c;
```

This is not the best way to read a text file, use

```
while(in >> c) { /* process c here */ }
```

or

```
while(in >> std::noskipws >> c) { /* process c here */ }
```

if you want the white spaces (like `\n`) included.

If your file is in binary, then it doesn't make too much sense to display it, but if you want, then use `get()` but test `if(!in) break;` before further processing

```
c = in.get();
if (!in) break; // test the stream
cout << c;      // then process
```

If you just want to display the file, the easiest way is to use the stream buffer directly, like

```
std::cout << in.rdbuf(); // display the whole file at once
```

Related: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: I don't read eof, cause I break the loop.
if (in.eof())
            break;

Comment: @MasterOfLife say you are at the end of the file (immediately before EOF). Then you test `if(in.eof())`, which will be false (you didn't yet reach EOF). Next you read `c = in.get()`, now you get the EOF in `c`. You should test for EOF **after** you read, and if the stream is EOF then discard the read (and break from the loop). In your case, change the order of `if` and `c = in.get()`, that is, put `c = in.get()` at the top of the loop. I highly recommend you to carefully read the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

The `istream::get()` method returns an *untranslated* value from the input stream.

If the value is not printable, your console may translate the character to '?'.

A better method is to print the value of the character along with the character:

```
cout << "\'" << c << "\', 0x" << hex << ((unsigned int) c) << endl;
```

This will allow you to see unprintable characters.